# Why an error occurs when I try to execute query by R::exec from RedBeanPHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, redbean

I have some code:

```php
        $done_tasks = R::getCol('SELECT count(*) FROM tasks WHERE `status` = "done" AND id IN
        (SELECT task_id FROM tasksemployess WHERE employee_id = ?)', array($_SESSION['employee']['id']));

        $failed_tasks = R::getCol('SELECT count(*) FROM tasks WHERE `status` = "failed" AND id IN
        (SELECT task_id FROM tasksemployess WHERE employee_id = ?)', array($_SESSION['employee']['id']));

        $process_tasks = R::getCol('SELECT count(*) FROM tasks WHERE `status` = "in_process" 
        OR `status` = "cheking" OR `status` = "remaking" AND id IN
        (SELECT task_id FROM tasksemployess WHERE employee_id = ?)', array($_SESSION['employee']['id']));

        $avg_mark = R::getCol('SELECT avg(mark) FROM tasks WHERE id IN
        (SELECT task_id FROM tasksemployess WHERE employee_id = ?)', array($_SESSION['employee']['id']));

        R::exec('UPDATE FROM persresults SET done_tasks = ?, failed_tasks = ?, process_tasks = ?, avarage_mark = ?,
        WHERE employee_id = ?',array($done_tasks[0], $failed_tasks[0], $process_tasks[0], $avg_mark[0], $_SESSION['employee']['id']));
```

All requests except the last return an array, so in the last request I refer to them as an array and with this, it seems, everything is correct, but:

> UPDATE FROM persresults SET done_tasks = 3, failed_tasks = 0,
>   process_tasks = 0, avarage_mark = '67.0000', WHERE employee_id = 19 An
>   error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM persresults SET done_tasks = 3, failed_tasks = 0,
>   process_tasks = 0, avarag' at line 1

As you can see, the values for the insert are passed as needed, but for some reason this error occurs.

Comment: You shouldn't have a `FROM` in your `UPDATE` query. Just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use UPDATE FROM (just UPDATE table_name)  and you have a wrong comma before WHERE in your update

```
 R::exec('UPDATE persresults 
    SET done_tasks = ?
    , failed_tasks = ?
    , process_tasks = ?
    , avarage_mark = ?
   WHERE employee_id = ?',array($done_tasks[0], 
         $failed_tasks[0],
         $process_tasks[0],
         $avg_mark[0], $_SESSION['employee']['id']));
```